# Distinguish between blank lines by their position (beginning, in-between or end of paragraphs)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please look at following example

> [BLANK LINE/S]
>
> First Paragraph
>
> [BLANK LINE Between Paragraphs]
>
> Second Paragraph
>
> [BLANK LINE Between Paragraphs]
>
> Third Paragraph
>
> [BLANK LINE/S End of Paragraphs]

Here are blank lines at the beginning, middle and end of paragraphs. I want to distinguish between them and take separate action for each.

The following code only find blank lines, but can not tell whether it is at the beginning or end or in-between paragraphs.

```
for line in myinfile:
    if line in ['\n', '\r', '\r\n']:
        pass
```

or,

```
for line in myinfile:
    if line.strip() == "":
        pass
```

What might be the solution here?

Comment: You can't distinguish between blank lines between paragraphs and blank lines at the end, unless you also know if you are at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do this by iterating over a list of strings (eg newline delimited text) at least once before taking any actions. You can then store the index' of the blanks in 3 separate lists. Thing is you really need to iterate over the whole thing before you know which the `end_blanks` are.

```py
text = """

First Paragraph


Second Paragraph


Third Paragraph

"""

start_blanks = []
mid_blanks = []
end_blanks = []
start = True

for idx, line in enumerate(text.splitlines()):
    if start and line == "":
        start_blanks.append(idx)
    elif start and line != "":
        start = False
    elif line == "":
        end_blanks.append(idx)
    elif line != "":
        # append current end_blanks to mid_blanks and
        # reset end_blanks
        mid_blanks.extend(end_blanks)
        end_blanks = []

print(f"Start blanks are lines: {start_blanks}")
print(f"Mid blanks are lines: {mid_blanks}")
print(f"End blanks are lines: {end_blanks}")
```

*output*

```
Start blanks are lines: [0, 1]
Mid blanks are lines: [3, 4, 6, 7]
End blanks are lines: [9]
```